# Mock ngx-restangular for unit testing Angular 5 app

Tags: unit-testing, angular5

I saw https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ngx-restangular/blob/master/demo/mock-data/mock-providers.ts as an answer to a similar question asked previously but i could not understand how to use this. Can someone please explain this?

My issue-

I have a service method-

```
restoreProject(project) {
        this.restangular.one('projects', project.id).get();
    }
```

How do i mock restangular for this?

Till now I have

```
beforeEach(() => {

    this.injector = Injector.create([
        {provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass: MockBackend, deps: []},
        {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions, deps: []},
        {provide: Restangular, useClass: Restangular, deps:[]},
        {provide: ProjectService, useClass: ProjectService, deps:[Restangular]}
    ]);

    this.service = this.injector.get(ProjectService);
    this.backend = this.injector.get(ConnectionBackend) as MockBackend;
    this.backend.connections.subscribe((connection: any) => this.connection = connection);

});

it('should query restore project', () => {

            this.service.restoreProject({id: 2});

            expect(this.connection.request.url).toMatch('projects/2');
        }));
```

But this gives the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createRequest' of undefined
    at Object.resource.(anonymous function) [as get] (http://0.0.0.0:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/home/app/node_modules/ngx-restangular/dist/esm/src/ngx-restangular-config.factory.js:475:1)
    at Object.elemFunction (http://0.0.0.0:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/home/app/node_modules/ngx-restangular/dist/esm/src/ngx-restangular.js:396:1)
    at wrapper (http://0.0.0.0:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/home/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4968:1)
    at Object.getFunction (http://0.0.0.0:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/home/app/node_modules/ngx-restangular/dist/esm/src/ngx-restangular.js:405:1)
    at Object.wrapper [as get] (http://0.0.0.0:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/home/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4968:1)
    at CommunicatorProjectService.restoreProject (http://0.0.0.0:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/home/app/src/app/budget-and-time-estimator/shared/communicator-project/communicator-project.service.ts:21:54)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://0.0.0.0:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/home/app/src/app/budget-and-time-estimator/shared/communicator-project/communicator-project.service.spec.ts:35:17)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://0.0.0.0:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/home/app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://0.0.0.0:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/home/app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://0.0.0.0:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/home/app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)
```